# How to design empty cells in UITableViewController like other

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I have UITableViewController with dynamic table. In prototype cell I add image. How to do that image was show in empty cell too? It is important for my app design.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> TableViewCell
    {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CellidQ", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
            var quest  = quests[indexPath.row]
            cell.questTextView.text=quest.text
            cell.tag=indexPath.row
            cell.delegate=self
                cell.questTextView.editable=false
                cell.questTextView.userInteractionEnabled=false
        cell.questTextView.delegate=self
        cell.questTextView.tag=indexPath.row
        return cell
    }
```

Comment: Can you show the cellForRow: code?

Comment: @Akhilrajtr I did it

Comment: What do you mean by show image on empty cell?

Answer (score 0):

HI for me you first have to create a new cocoa touch class inheriting from tableviewcell class.
There you can create image or button... to customise it.
then you set this  class name to your  prototype cell.

IN your cellForRowAtIndexPath you can call and load you customise cell.
like this

```
    let cell = yourcellclassname(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")

    cell.textLabel?.text = cellContent[indexPath.row]
   cell.imageview?.image = cellContent[indexPath.row]

       hope it helps.!
```